# Render partial view dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

I've one more question. I have a view which is containing an "add" link. Everytime I press this link a partial view should be added dynamically (for example with jQuery).

I've tried to do that by this way:

```
 $('#Div1').load('<%= Url.Action( "Video", "ddd", new { id = "1", url="ko" } ) %>');
```

But this method do not **add** a partial it just **replace** the content of "Div1" with the partial.

When I try:

```
$('#Div1').append('<%= Url.Action( "Video", "ddd", new { id = "1", url="ko" } ) %>');
```

there is something added to my Div but no partial view. Just the path of the partial view is added: `/de/Market/ddd/Video/1?url=ko`

My code in the controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Video(string url, int id)
        {
            ViewModels.Video v = new Video();
            v.URL = url;
            v.ID_Video = id;
            return PartialView("Video", v);

        }
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?
(I'm using MVC2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add your dynamically loaded content wrapped in individual divs to #Div1 as a container:

```
$('<div>').appendTo('#Div1').load('<%= Url.Action( "Video", "ddd", new { id = "1", url="ko" } ) %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('#Div1').append(...)
```

This should help.

Comment: You mean `$('#Div1').append(...)`